# Issue with Overriding Default Keybinding in Atom Text Editor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I'm attempting to modify my keybindings in Atom.

So far I've been successful in adding a custom **new** keybindings via the `keymap.cson` file. However, I've encountered a problem when attempting to override a default one.

I'm trying to replace the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, which is bound to `Save as` by default, to perform the `Save all` command instead. Of course, merely adding didn't work, so after a while I figured out I should `unset!` the key combination first. Now it looked way more promissing in the Key Binding Resolver.

**This keymap produced following output in the Key Binding Resolver:**

```
'body':
'unset!': 'core:save-as'
'ctrl-shift-S': 'core:save-all' # Key Binding Resolver claims this works fine
                                # but it doesn't do anything
'ctrl-shift-E': 'editor-stats:toggle' # works fine

'atom-text-editor':
'ctrl-shift-A': 'bracket-matcher:select-inside-brackets' # works fine
```

[image: Screenshot of Key Binding Resolver]

Despite that, however, the key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> doesn't save anything at all. Accessing the command from the context menu works fine. I've searched the web, the `core:save-all` command seems to exist, it even has a default keybinding on Mac.

I am using the latest version of Atom on Windows 10, made sure no package conflicts with the keybind.

I'm really confused about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find commands by using the command palette.

- Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
- Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Looking for "save all" there, the only match for me is

> Window: Save All

Ignore whatever key binding it may show next to it. What is important is the command name, "Window: Save All". You can convert that to a command selector with these steps:

1. Lowercase everything
2. Remove the space after `:`
3. Replace other spaces with `-`

This yields your selector: `window:save-all`.

So your key binding should be:

```
'ctrl-shift-s': 'window:save-all'
```

As the command's name suggests, this will save all tabs in all panes *in the current window*. It should not affect anything in other Atom windows.

Comment: Now I see - unlike the `save` and `save-as` commands, `save-all` is located under `window`, rather than `core`... I should have thought of searching the command palette, will keep that in mind for future reference. Everything now works like a charm, thank you!